# MySQL WildFly integration

Tags: mysql, connection, wildfly

`com/mysql/main/module.xml` and I put `mysql-connector-jar` here:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.mysql">
        <resources>
         <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar"/>
     </resources>
     <dependencies>
      <module name="javax.api"/>
     </dependencies>
    </module>
```

datasource and driver in standalone.xml

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:/MySQLDS" pool-name="MySQLDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db3</connection-url>
                    <driver>MySQLDriver</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name></user-name>
                        <password></password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="MySQLDriver" module="com.mysql">
                        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

persistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="1.0">
    <!-- MySQL Datasource -->
    <persistence-unit name="JPADB">
        <jta-data-source>java:/MySQLDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And I am getting

```
IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
```

error when I run the WildFly 8.

Comment: Try adding a module dependency for `javax.transaction.api`. Here's an example of creating an XA datasource with CLI https://gist.github.com/jamezp/1c0875660cf0f2621bfa1e85bf675196.

Comment: It would also be helpful to post the full error if that guide doesn't help